# Getting Server Error in '/' Application.Using PHP Code on IIS

Tags: php, iis-7.5, wamp

I create a blog with php coding but my site is hosted at IIS 7.5 .
here is the link 
http://test.beingstudent.com.pk/blog/blogsview.php?blgid=32
when click on link in blog its give me that error 
Server Error in '/' Application.

[image]

but when i run this same code on my local server which has WAMP install its not givng me error and redirect to the link in the blog

Comment: I think you need to add redirect_module at Apache server of wamp or add htaccess at root.

Comment: my site is hosted at IIS 7.5 server ...

Comment: So, simple question where did you place your project files.

Comment: i didnt get ur question .. what i guess with ur question i place my code at IIS server

Comment: If you are using wamp then you need to place your php project code at C:\wamp\www\ lets say you place wamp in C drive. then access that folder by using http://localhost/your_project_folder

Comment: its not problem on my localhost machine at my localhost i got Wamp and its working fine . But i upload my project to webhosting and its running IIS 7.5 .. and i am getting this error over there .. is there any solution about that

Comment: So you need to contact your server administrator for this.